# Eliminate duplicates and Insert Unique records having max no. of column values present through Talend

Tags: excel, duplicates, unique, primary-key, talend

[image]

I have an excel file which gets updated on a daily basis i.e the data is always different every time.

I am pulling the data from the Excel sheet into the table using **Talend**. I have a primary key `Company_ID` defined in the table.

The error I am facing is that the Excel sheet has few duplicate `Company_ID` values. It will also pick up more duplicate values in the future as the Excel file will be updated daily.

I want to choose the first record where the `Company ID` field is `1` and the record doesn't have null in the rest of the columns. Also, for a `Company_ID` of `3` there is a null value for one column which is ok since it is a unique record for that `company_id`.

How do I choose a unique row which has maximum no. of column values present ie for eg in the case of `Company ID` of `1` in Talend ?

Comment: Identify duplicate and unique.. Tuniquerow picks the first unique record.. I dnt need the first unique record.. Incase the record is duplicate in the second or any other row with all column values then i need that record.

Comment: The file is on the cloud and I do not have access on it. The file is handled via a component and just the data is being stored into the table. Thanks anyways..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tUniqRow is usually the easiest way to handle duplicates.
If you are worried that the first row coming to tUniqRow may not be the first row that you want there, you can sort your rows, so they enter tUniqRow in your preferred order:

[image: DIAGRAM]
(used components: tFileInputExcel, tJavaRow, tSortRow, tUniqRow, tFilterColumns)

In your particular case, the tJava could look like this:

```
// Code generated according to input schema and output schema
output_row.company_id = input_row.company_id;
output_row.name       = input_row.name;
output_row.et_cetera  = input_row.et_cetera;
// End of pre-generated code

int i = 0;
if (input_row.company_id == null) { i++; }
if (input_row.name       == null) { i++; }
if (input_row.et_cetera  == null) { i++; }
output_row.priority = i;
```