# Identify unique record from duplicates in Talend

Tags: excel, postgresql, duplicates, primary-key, talend

http://postimg.org/image/89yglfakx/

Refer the above link for the image as a reference.

I have an excel file which gets updated on a daily basis i.e the data is always different every time.
I am pulling the **data from the excel sheet into the table using Talend**. I have a primary key **Company_ID** defined in the table.
The error I am facing is that the Excel sheet has few duplicate **Company_ID** values.
It will also pick up more duplicate values in the future as the excel Excel file will be updated on a daily basis ,so it will have different duplicate values in **Company_ID** field. 
I want to choose the unique data record for the **Company ID 1**,the record that doesn't have null in the rest of the columns.
For **Company_ID 3** ,there is a null value for the columns which is ok since it is a unique record for that company_id.
How do I choose a unique row which has maximum no. of column values present ie for eg in the case of **Company ID 1** in **Talend** ?
I tried using **Tuniqrow** but it uniquely picks up the first record from the duplicates,so if my first record has null values from the duplicate Company ID then it won't work.

Comment: looks like your rules for identifying the unique record varies for each company_id..if its 1 then its different. if its 2 then its different? is this correct. And do you know how many different company_id can there be?

Comment: Duplicated ! http://stackoverflow.com/q/32905948/2037229